# Right to left layout in android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I come from a web application development background and i am new to android, I am trying to create an application which has a right to left layout (Arabic) but I am facing a lot of problems with the alignment and text alignment, I understand that many people complain about android's support for rtl languages but I can see that there are many rtl applications in the android market which work just fine. 
Is there a simple clear way to handle rtl layout or do I have to do workarounds to reach a desired layout?
Note: I am trying to develop using android 2.3 and 3.0 SDK

Thanks

Comment: You can use layout parameters like [`layout_alignParentStart`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentStart) instead of `layout_alignParentLeft`.  Is that the kind of thing you're asking about?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Bidi helps you at all, it's just a Object to give you some information about your text.

Answer (score 0):

I know that in "*Developer options*" on Android phones you can change "RTL mode" to be enabled. I'm not fully certain if that helps. I [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32015734/4990978) to another SO post asking about this for Left handed people.

I hope you have an awesome day, and be well!