# Detect "left handed mode" setting

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I'm looking into these docs: [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html), [Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html) and others, but I cannot find anything useful related to Left handed layout.

As far as I know Android 2.3 had that setting. Right now I am unsure if it was deprecated or not. Is there a way to detect if "left handed mode" is set?

*Left Handed Mode* is possibly similar to "*Force RTL Layout Direction*" In "*Developer Options*".

Answer (score 0):

There was never an Android standard setting added to the API for a 'left handed mode'. You may have seen a manufacturer specific change to Android, but I don't know of any recent Android device that has a similar feature.

Answer (score 0):

Individual Android app developers may add the option to switch to a "left handed mode" that will alter the UI to be better formatted for users who hold phones and devices in there left hands. I am an active "*Lefty rights*" advocate in the app world and call-out developers who could easily better accommodate left handed people. As far as a handicap/accessibility setting there is no current setting on Android for that. There is actually a RTL layout setting in "Developer options" you can enable it through [these instructions](http://lifehacker.com/enable-androids-secret-right-to-left-layout-if-youre-le-1676267178), and apps like Chrome and Google Maps use it. I would think some more research would need to be done to check for that seeing how it's a developer option and not an accessibility option. My guess would be it is similar to getting the device *locale* and adjusting. I'm not sure if you could find the developer options in resources though. (Noting for full disclosure, the last time I programmed android was a few months ago.)

I would buy a phone that had RTL/ Lefty Mode perfectly implemented though.

Hope this helps a little.

Have an awesome day, and be well!